# list only files of a directory and ignore the subdirectories with python

Tags: python, path, operating-system, os.walk, listdir

I would like to list only the files of a directory and skip the subdirectories.

The current code lists also the files in the subdirectories but that's not what I want:

```
import os 

list_files = []    
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_folder):
        for filename in files:
            joined = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
            list_files.append(joined)
```

The files in the directory to process look like this:

```
/headfolder/subfolder/subfile.pdf     #ignore this directory
/headfolder/subfolder2/subfile.pdf    #ignore this directory
/headfolder/file.pdf                  #get this path 
/headfolder/file2.pdf                 #get this path
```

desired output:

```
['/headfolder/file.pdf','/headfolder/file2.pdf ']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files=[i for i in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(i)]
```

Edit:

**for list all files in specific direcotry**

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

input_folder = 'headfolder/'
list_files = []

files = [f for f in listdir(input_folder) if isfile(join(input_folder, f))]
for filename in files:
    joined = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
    list_files.append(joined)

print(list_files)
```

Comment: i need the input to be a specific directory, not the current directory.  If i do ```os.listdir(input_folder)``` , I get an empty list as output.

Comment: the edit is just what I was looking for, thanks!